h float specifier changed to ht
I am getting
LaTeX Warning: `h' float specifier changed to `ht'.

h is an option to place the float here, i.e., approximately at the same point it occurs in the source text (however, not exactly at the spot).  Thus if h should place the float only approximately, the option description is non-functioning.

The question is different.  Does h mean exactly here or approximately here.

Please read the answer and references therein.

To mean exactly here there is the argument H,  So latex should not change h to ht.  But do what h is supposed to do.  Without messaging the user about anything.

H is a non standard option added by a package and really should never be needed, the only reason to put text in a float is to allow it to be moved and the only reason to use H is to stop it moving, so a more consistent approach would be to not use a floating environment.

Correct.  But for float one should allow possibility for placing to the top or bottom.  And the user should not be informed where it was placed.  The title of the suggested answer is misleading because I am using h float specifier when specifying a float.  Or perhaps not, does figure make a float ?

yes figure and table environments make floats (that is their only purpose, they are not directly related to including images or making tabular layout)


The question is different. Does h mean exactly here or approximately here.

It doesn't mean either, it means do not allow the float at the top of the page or the bottom of the page or on a page on its own as it means the option is removing the t b and p possibilities.
That means that if the float does not fit exactly at that position (which for example for a float that is half textheight high will occur on average half the time as the natural position will fall more than half way down the page) then the float may not be positioned anywhere.
In the original latex that would mean that [h] floats usually drifted to the end of the document where they were flushed out, but in latex2e if the [h] float can not be placed at its position in the source then h is changed to ht with that warning to allow the float to be placed at the top of the next page.

Contrasting it with H, it is sensible to have h to mean approximately here.  Then if the float is placed with some shift, it would be something to be expected, without needing a warning.  At this moment it looks to me that I have done something wrong,

I fail to understand how placing something with the possibility of some drift be interpreted to exclude the t or b possibilities.  Because then you actually change it to include t or b as well.  In essence one can assume that h includes possibility for t or b.  No need to warn users.

I also have this problem that I use documents with two columns.  A bad point is that figures are placed only at the top of the page or on their own page.  Specifying their position using modifiers like h or b, they will be ignored.

@Vinkel no. in two column mode single column figures (figure) support all the htbp options.  spanning figures (figure*) support t or p  (h wouldn't really make sense) and you can add b with the dblfloatfix and some other packages

The figures span more than a single column.  And the pain is all these packages to apply fixes.  Where fixes should really be applied to the actual implementation.

How does h not make sense, when it is not actually enforced ?  Perhaps there should be another option that allows drift of whatever.  Then, apply whatever drift is necessary,  And we would not have to worry about t or b which are actually enforced rather than allow drifting.  For me, allowing drifting should means a figure that is allowed to float around, rather than enforcing t, b, or p.

Why don't you allow drifting text between two column text in a page ?

you can't have a two column span mid-page breaking both columns, I can't understand your comment I ssupect that your mental model does not match what latex is doing, latex calls it floating not drifting and once something floats it may be placed in one of the areas here, top, bottom, page, so mostly if you use an optional argument you are restricting the places that the float may be placed so removing flrxibility and, if you remove p making it more likely the float can not be placed at all.

If I want a float, then I should not use h or any option actually. Is a float capable of being placed in the middle of a two column page ?

"If I want a float, then I should not use h or any option actually" is actually a non sequitur.

If you haven't already done so, please study the posting How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?

Why does it not follow ?  David explained that use of the figure optional arguments  restrict the places that the float may be placed, so removing flexibility.  Thus if I want flexibility, I should not use the optional arguments.

@Vinkel no I did not say that. the default positions in most classes are tbp (although that is user settable) in which case you need the option to allow h but you should almost never use it on its own [htbp] allows all areas, as I said already you can use h on a single column float but there is no h area for two column floats it wouldn't really make sense and it's certainly not implemented even if you could imagine what it might mean.

"At this moment it looks to me that I have done something wrong" you have done something wrong: you have specified [h] so removing all other possibilities and used this at a position where h is not possible. So you have incorrect input and get a warning, the system is working as designed.

I just removed any options, so my updated command simply says \begin{figure}.  Can floating figures be inserted between text or only designed for placement at top or bottom ?

@Vinkel as I said above the default in most classes is [tbp] so not allowing h. If you want to allow h then you need to change the default or use an option such as [htbp]

So in reality if one wants figures embedded within the text. it is basically just t or b for multicolumn text.  But for single column, the option h has tho capability of inserting the figure in the middle of the page with text above and below it.  I understand correctly now ?

you can use h in a two column document for a float within a column (figure) but not for a float spanning two columns (figure*) as that wouldn't have any obvious meaning anyway. @Vinkel
